# How can I handle Web.Config file with different environments (dev,test,staging) in Visual Studio Team Services with GIT?

Tags: git, web-config, environment-variables, connection-string, azure-devops

I have 3 branches (dev,test,staging) in my web project based on VSTS and GIT. They were modified with specific  `<connectionStrings>` in `Web.Config` depending on the environment I'm working on. Additionally, I added manually Services References which points to specific URL and they were added automatically to `<applicationSettings>` based on the environment as well.

I've been working fine with those tree environments; However, when I started to merge two branches, my `Web.Config` file was modified and my Services References were changed also. These scenario forced me to add change all the configurations manually, so I'm wondering If there is an easier way to handle merging branches without losing all configuration previously stated or any way to work with multiple environments without doing manual stuff.

Comment: What do you think of Daniel's answer? Does it meet your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Create generalized configuration files with placeholders and then inject the correct values at the time of deployment. This, of course relies on you having build and deployment automation in place. Which you should.